# What bug is this?

Tags: bug-identification, singapore

Found this on my living room wall. I live on the ground floor with lots of plants right outside the window. Have spotted a similar looking bug outside on the road near the area too.

[image: bug in the living room]

[image: same bug outside]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a [Tropical leatherleaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_leatherleaf) slug.

> The Tropical Leatherleaf (Laevicaulis alte) is found in both urban and forested areas. The animal is brownish, usually with darker speckles, and has a pale line on its back. It is not known whether it is native or not, though scientists think it is most likely introduced. It can grow to about 4cm long.

[Terrestrial & Freshwater Gastropods (Snails & Slugs) of Singapore](http://tidechaser.blogspot.com/2012/12/terrestrial-freshwater-snails-slugs.html)

> The Tropical Leatherleaf (Laevicaulis alte sensu lato, tak nang) is a flat, brown slug which often hides its tentacles. It is well adapted to the dry lowlands, hiding underground at daytime, and feeding on your plants at night.

[On slugs and snails](https://dokmaidogma.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/on-slugs-and-snails/) (Definitely check the picture here which matches yours quite nicely.)

There is also an **album of pictures** [here](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/85102-Laevicaulis-alte/browse_photos), and a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFsp_xo1ufw).